# TinyMCE menus not working inside bootstrap modal

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, tinymce

When placing a TinyMCE editor inside a bootstrap modal, the editor is visible and functioning, however when clicking a menu item the menu doesn't show up.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add the folowing css

```
.tox-tinymce-aux {
    z-index: 999999!important;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Bootstrap blocks all `focusin` calls from elements outside the dialog. To render TinyMCE instances inside a Bootstrap dialog, add the following code:

```
// Prevent Bootstrap dialog from blocking focusin
$(document).on('focusin', function(e) {
  if ($(e.target).closest(".tox-tinymce-aux, .moxman-window, .tam-assetmanager-root").length) {
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
  }
});
```

Here is an example: http://fiddle.tinymce.com/gRgaab

Comment: The issue here is not, that the menus aren't working, the issue is that they are appearing below the modal and are thus not visible.